# Installing Ubuntu Dektop, but using as a server

Tags: 14.04, server

Is it possible to use Ubuntu Desktop as a Server? Can I host a website on it?
What are the additional packages i need to install to make my system both as a desktop and a server

Comment: Not like that. Can we use Ubuntu server as a desktop.

Comment: LOL I mean can we use Desktop Ubuntu as a server ?..  By installing some software packages

Comment: Well I host my website on desktop - http://timhitchins.now.im I have installed apache and php (lamp server).

Comment: Thats what i'm ASking..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. You can host a website etc on Ubuntu Desktop by installing the relevant packages:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 lampserver^
```

Example - [my website](http://timhitchins.now.im) is hosted on my computer.